# mixing two custom filters with pixi js

Tags: shader, pixi.js

I'm trying to add custom filters to a sprite like this:

```
sprite.filters = [
    new PIXI.Filter(undefined, SHADER_STRINGS["hue-rotate-shader-fs"], {
                    uHueShift: 90,              
                }),
            new PIXI.Filter(undefined, SHADER_STRINGS["contrast-shader-fs"], {
                    uContrast:50,                   
            }) 
            
                ];
```

but only the last one in the filters array gets applied. In the previous case, only the contrast is applied and in this case:

```
sprite.filters = [
    new PIXI.Filter(undefined, SHADER_STRINGS["contrast-shader-fs"], {
            uContrast:50,                   
    }) 
        new PIXI.Filter(undefined, SHADER_STRINGS["hue-rotate-shader-fs"], {
            uHueShift: 90,              
    }),
                
    ];
```

only the hue shift is applied.

Please note that this doesn't happen with the built in filters like blur and noise as I can mix them with no problem.

My guess is that the last shader takes the untouched texture every time. What can I do to fix this so I can add multiple filters to a sprite at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second frag shader is missing something, consider your previously generated color especially its alpha channel in your second frag shader and mix them together based on their both alpha channel.

I've tested in PIXI@6.0.2 and uSampler always has previous filter on it.